# Make TableView buttons take up less memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have code here that generates a list of cells that contain buttons.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to make it so that I am creating 1 button object instead of 20, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that?

I need some guidance as to where to make it so I only create 1 button object.

Additionally, I might be making 20 cell objects when I only need 1 as well?

I don't totally understand how to utilize memory well yet.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //[cell sizeToFit];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if([cell.contentView viewWithTag:3] != nil){
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 50);
    button.tag = 3;

    int rows = [yourDefaultActivities count];
    int rowsl = rows - 1;

    float r = 1+(((255-1+75)/rowsl)*(indexPath.row));

    if(r > 255){
        r = 255;
    }

    float g = 255-(((255-1+75)/rowsl)*(indexPath.row));

    if(g < 0){
        g = 255-fabsf(g);
    }else{
        g = 255;
    }
    float b = 1;

    UIColor *thisColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255 green:g/255 blue:b/255 alpha:1];

    button.backgroundColor = thisColor;

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
    [button setTitle:[[yourDefaultActivities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];

    [cell addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: I tried to remove the buttons every time I created a new one, but I must be doing it wrong..

Comment: Your allready added subviews tend to stay there on reused cell-s. A simple nonoptimized method would be to add `for (UIView *aView in cell.contentView.subviews){[aView removeFromSuperView];}` right after you create/dequeue a cell. This is actually a bad coding practice but might help you getting started.

Comment: @rokjarc I see where you're going but this code doesn't seem to do anything. Additionally why is it bad practice?

Comment: Bad practice is because it is slow. Better one would be subclassing a `UITableViewCell`. But it still should get rid of those "wrong color" corners...

Comment: Oh - you're adding to `cell`, not `cell.contentView`. Then change the code to `for (UIView *aView in cell.subviews){[aView removeFromSuperView];}`

Comment: Oh I see the corners are because there are button subviews behind the buttons?

Comment: Yes! And you should remove them before adding the others.

Comment: @rokjark Okay well now it's working, but how do I add the new ones when I remove one?

Comment: Just as you did before. This code simply cleans up the previous stuff.

Comment: I think I can do that but it requires me to know what end of the screen the object is being removed from so i can add an object to the opposite end, correct?

Comment: @rokjarc Also, I'm going to need to add two buttons inside these existing buttons to detect which side of the "parent button" has been clicked. Will this be a memory issue with 8 parent buttons and 16 child buttons on the screen at any given time?

Comment: Whoa - when adding buttons to a button memory issues are the least of your concern - you should rethink your UI. You could add buttons to an `UIView` though or any other container though. If this cell of yours is going to be a complex one you might want to find a good tutorial on sublassing `UItableViewCell`.

Comment: @rokjarc okay. What about my question about readding the buttons..? You said to "do it the same way as before" but that doesn't really work haha... I can use the same button and cell code, but I'm not sure how to add it at the correct cell index?

Comment: sorry, i read "adding" the buttons. Tags can help you "read" the buttons - see rdelmar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One button object can't appear in 8 cells at once -- you do need as many cells and buttons as will fit on the screen at any time (it looks like 8 or 9). But 8 or 9 cell with buttons in them should not cause any memory problems -- buttons aren't that expensive. The problem with the code you posted though, is that it is adding buttons every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, which happens a lot when you scroll. Since cells are reused, you don't want to be adding a button to a cell that already has one. The easiest solution, in my opinion, is to make a custom cell in the storyboard, and add you buttons there. You can still set their color in code based on the indexPath so you get the look you want. Alternately, you can check whether the cell (actually the cell.contentView which is where you should be adding them, not directly to the cell) has a subview of class UIButton, and only add a button if it doesn't already have one.

**After Edit:**

In answer to your comment, you don't need to make the rounded button in the storyboard, you can just add a button (type custom) to your subclassed cell, and then modify its look in code. Here is an example of what I mean. In this test app, I created a custom cell class (RDCell) and changed the class of the cell in the storyboard to that. I added a custom button to the cell, positioned and sized it with constraints, and made an IBOutlet to it in RDCell.h. Here is what I have in the table view controller:

```
#import "TableController.h"
#import "RDCell.h"

@implementation TableController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(RDCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:.15 + (indexPath.row/30.0) saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];
    cell.button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    cell.button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}

-(void)customActionPressed:(UIButton *) sender {
    NSLog(@"button pressed in row: %d",sender.tag);
   [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

This was the resultant view:

[image]

I put a log in initWithCoder for RDCell, and it's called only 12 times (the max. number of cells on the screen at any one time), so there's never more than 12 cells or 12 buttons.

Comment: I also tried to do your first suggestion and couldn't create a rounded button in the storyboard so I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @maxhud, You don't need to make the rounded button in  the storyboard to get a rounded button. See my edit.

Comment: This worked very well for me. Thank you so much. I have one question that isn't related to the original that you could probably answer quickly but you don't have to if you don't want to - How can I resize the cell when the button is clicked? I already know how to link the button click to an IBAction, but what function might I use inside the IB action?

Comment: @maxhud, you would have to set a property (an integer or indexPath) that you check in heightForRowAtIndexPath, and then reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to update the table.

Comment: so if I wanted to animate it, I couldn't use a built in animation function, I would have to animate manually, yes?

Comment: @maxhud,no, you can animate it when you reload the row. So if you created an NSInteger property, selectedRow, you would set that equal to the indexPath.row in the button's action method, then call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. In heightForRowAtIndexPath, check if indexPath.row equals selectedRow and return a larger number if it does-- "return (indexPath.row == selectedRow)? 100 : 44;"